# Adding R.sq value as column in data frame along with regression coefficients

Tags: r, regression, modeling

I am building a multiple regression model with group by functionality so close to 100+ model grouped by each sub_category. I want to add Adj. R sq. and R sq. value in a new data frame have coefficient. I am able to create a table with just regression coefficient but unable to add R sq. value.

R Code:

```
dat <- data.table(main_df)
df_coeff<- dat[,list(intercept=coef(lm(y~x1+x2+x3))[1], coef_price=coef(lmlm(y~x1+x2+x3)))[2],coef_discount=coef(lmlm(y~x1+x2+x3)))[3], coef_clicks=coef(lm(y~x1+x2+x3)))[4], rsq= summary((lm(lm(y~x1+x2+x3)))$r.squared[5]), by=subcatg_id]
```

I have this present table structure and would like to add r.sq to existing table so that can see the R.sq of each model.[The existing table but no rsq column][1]

The R code for this dataframe I presently have:

```
df_coeff<- dat[,list(intercept=coef(lm(y~x1+x2+x3))[1], coef_price=coef(lmlm(y~x1+x2+x3)))[2],coef_discount=coef(lmlm(y~x1+x2+x3)))[3], coef_clicks=coef(lm(y~x1+x2+x3)))[4], by=subcatg_id]

#Calculating elasticity
df_coeff$exp_price<- exp(df_coeff$coef_price)
df_coeff$exp_discount<- exp(df_coeff$coef_discount)
df_coeff$exp_clicks<- exp(df_coeff$coef_clicks)
df_coeff$exp_elasticity<- df_coeff$exp_price+df_coeff$exp_discount+df_coeff$exp_clicks
df_coeff$elasticity<- apply(cbind(df_coeff$exp_price,df_coeff$exp_discount,df_coeff$exp_clicks),1,sum,na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: You should a) replace the link to an image of your dataset with r-code that creates it, and b) detail which algorithm you propose for making "adj. R sq.".  Refer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48703/what-is-the-adjusted-r-squared-formula-in-lm-in-r-and-how-should-it-be-interpret if you are unaware about the fact that `adj_R_sq` is quite ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the post now. I will be using default adj. R. sq which is produced in summary(model) and based on the link it is Wherry’s formula. Also my exact model equation is

lm(formula = log(unit_sales) ~ log(unit_price) + log(discount) + 
    log(clicks), data = sub_cat1_6407, na.action = na.omit)

Comment: The `summary` result applies to comparisons of 2 models and you are not doing that. This is likely to eventually spiral down to a discussion of whether you are a former SAS user and have consumed the "type III" Koolaid.

Comment: Yes I have been using outest=data; in SAS to create new dataset. But I am unable to add the R.sq. and adj. R sq.  in R data frame. What should be my approach as I am new to R programming.

I get r. sq vale of single run model by using 
rsq= summary(m1)$r.squared, where 
m1<-  lm(log(unit_sales) ~ log(unit_price) + log(discount) + log(clicks), data = sub_cat1_6407, na.action = na.omit). 
Cant we add r.sq and adj. rsq. in the dataframe I want by group by regression.

Comment: I've outlined the approach you should take. You appear to not be reading my earlier comments carefully. It appearsed you expected a separate adjRsq for each variable. I say again: do not post pictures of data output; post  something that can be pasted into a running R console session; and specify (preferably in R code) the algorithm for your coefficient-specific "adj_R_sq" entries.

Comment: I have removed the image just the code now. yes you are right for each row I want r.sq. as variable.

Comment: So you still need to specify how to calculate adj.r.sq for each variable. And post output of `dput(df_coeff)`

Comment: **ans$adj.r.squared <- 1 - (1 - ans$r.squared) * ((n - 
        df.int)/rdf)**


subcatg_id
intercept
coef_price
coef_discount
coef_clicks
exp_price
exp_discount
exp_clicks
exp_elasticity
elasticity
901
28217
-79.9611321
16.473924006
NA
-0.0693681273
14273625.2832322
NA
0.9329832
NA
14273626.216215